# Can I get a visa on arrival for India?

Tags: india, visas-on-arrival

I've heard that tourist visas on arrival are being extended to include more countries?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting in **October 2014**, [India will be extending their visa-on-arrival program to include 180 countries](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-india-26062351).

India currently offers visa-on-arrival to tourists from only 11 countries, including Finland, Singapore and Japan.

A quote from their Planning Minister on the matter:

> "We have decided to extend the visa-on-arrival facility to tourists
>   from 180 nations. It will take five to six months for the respective
>   departments to put the required infrastructure in place. We hope to
>   implement this from the next tourist session beginning October,"

The electronic visa-on-arrival will be available at 26 major airports in India and would be valid for 30 days from the date of the tourist's arrival in India.

Note, however, that this does not include all countries - for example, nationals from Pakistan, Sudan, Afghanistan, Iran, Iraq, Nigeria, Sri Lanka and Somalia still cannot get visas on arrival.

Comment: It looks like the extension to other countries has been pushed back to June 2015: http://www.firstpost.com/india/e-visas-may-make-visa-arrival-redundant-says-tourism-minister-naik-1741615.html

Comment: The list of countries was extended : http://www.indiatravelforum.in/threads/visa-on-arrival-in-india.29/